# Django Model - How to override save method and create another record

Tags: django, django-models

Let's say I have these two classes and I want to create and attach a collar record to each dog record that gets created like so:

```
class Collar(models.Model):
    serial_number =  models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, db_column='serial_number')
    weight = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'existing_table_from_before_django_was_born'

class Dog(models.Model):
    size = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    collar = models.OneToOneField(Collar,blank=True, null=True, editable=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.collar = Collar()
        if self.collar:
            self.collar.weight = '10'
            self.collar.save()
        super(Dog,self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

When I run this code, the new Collar record is getting created but the problem is that Dog.collar_id is showing up as null in the table.

The twist here as you can notice is that the Collar class references an existing table. I made its primary key be auto incrementing in MySQL but maybe something is going wrong there.

When I step through the save method, I see it creates the Collar object and updates the value but self.collar.serial_number prints 'none'.

Any ideas what could be happening?  I'd be forever grateful.  (I'm on 1.2.5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make your `Collar.serial_number` field an `AutoField`, so that Django knows it gets a value automatically on save.

Comment: That did the trick!  I wonder if it's worth updating the Django docs anywhere with this info?

Answer (score 1):

Your `Collar` doesn't *have* a PK until you save it, which means that assigning at that point won't work.

```
collar = Collar()
 ...
collar.save()
self.collar = collar
```

Comment: That still doesn't seem to work. But I think it's something I did, I'm going to update my question with a (maybe important) detail I left out.

Comment: That's not a "detail", that's a completely different question.